# Need some help converting an XML with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Need some help regarding the XSLT transformation of a flat file schema. Is it possible to combine the direct children of the `Record` node into one containing `Record` node? Child `512` is required and has min and max occurrence of 1 and marks the beginning of a new `Record` node.

**Input:**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns="">
    <Header>
        <node01>AA</node01>
        <node02>123</node02>
    </Header>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <node01>BB</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </512>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <513>
            <node01>CC</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </513>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <node01>DD</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </512>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <515>
            <node01>JJ</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </515>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <node01>EE</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </512>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <513>
            <node01>FF</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </513>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <514>
            <node01>GG</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </514>
        <514>
            <node01>HH</node01>
            <node02>123</node02>
        </514>
    </Record>
    <Footer>
        <node01>II</node01>
        <node02>123</node02>
    </Footer>
</ns0:Root>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns="">
    <Header>
        <item01>AA</item01>
        <item02>123</item02>
    </Header>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <item01>BB</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </512>
        <513>
            <item01>CC</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </513>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <item01>DD</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </512>
        <515>
            <item01>JJ</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </515>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <512>
            <item01>EE</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </512>
        <513>
            <item01>FF</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </513>
        <514>
            <item01>GG</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </514>
        <514>
            <item01>HH</item01>
            <item02>123</item02>
        </514>
    </Record>
    <Footer>
        <item01>II</item01>
        <item02>123</item02>
    </Footer>
</ns0:Root>
```

Thank you and kind regards
Philipp

P.S.: XSLT 2.0 is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not legal XML (element names can't start with numbers), but supposing you renamed all the invalid elements to start with "r", you can do the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record[r512]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="iterate" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Record" />

  <xsl:template match="Record" mode="iterate">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Record[1][not(r512)]"
                         mode="iterate"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns="" xmlns:ns0="nsss">
  <Header>
    <node01>AA</node01>
    <node02>123</node02>
  </Header>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>BB</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r513>
      <node01>CC</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r513>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>DD</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r515>
      <node01>JJ</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r515>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>EE</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r513>
      <node01>FF</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r513>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r514>
      <node01>GG</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r514>
    <r514>
      <node01>HH</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r514>
  </Record>
  <Footer>
    <node01>II</node01>
    <node02>123</node02>
  </Footer>
</ns0:Root>
```

Produces:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="nsss">
  <Header>
    <node01>AA</node01>
    <node02>123</node02>
  </Header>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>BB</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
    <r513>
      <node01>CC</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r513>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>DD</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
    <r515>
      <node01>JJ</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r515>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <r512>
      <node01>EE</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r512>
    <r513>
      <node01>FF</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r513>
    <r514>
      <node01>GG</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r514>
    <r514>
      <node01>HH</node01>
      <node02>123</node02>
    </r514>
  </Record>
  <Footer>
    <node01>II</node01>
    <node02>123</node02>
  </Footer>
</ns0:Root>
```